# Does the word "vain" necessarily have a negative denotation or connotation?

Tags: word-usage, translation, connotation

I don't really know how to answer my Brazilian students when they ask me how to say "vaidoso/a" in English. The Portuguese word does not convey a bad idea but "vain" does.

*Or does it*?

Comment: "Vain", when used to describe a person, is generally considered to be negative, since vanity is considered to be a moral failing (though certainly one that everyone possesses to a degree).  But the word can be used in other contexts:  "We tried to get that tree to grow, but all our efforts were in vain."

Comment: ["vaidade"](http://www.dicionariodoaurelio.com/Vaidade) and ["vaidoso/a"](http://www.dicionariodoaurelio.com/vaidoso) often have a negative connotation.  It all depends on context. Vanity is certainly not a quality to be admired in men.

Comment: @HotLicks I think that is sufficient enough for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From (online) [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/vain):

> **vain**(adjective)
>
> Having or showing an excessively high opinion of one's appearance,
> abilities, or  worth. "their flattery made him vain"
>
> *Synonyms:*   conceited, narcissistic, self-loving, in love with oneself, self-admiring, self-regarding, wrapped up in oneself,
> self-absorbed, self-obsessed, self-centred, egotistic, egotistical,
> egoistic, egocentric, egomaniac;
>
> *Antonyms*:modest

Vanity is most certainly not a virtue to be admired, as it indicates shallowness in character as well as an unhealthy obsession with the self.

**Self assuredness** is a quality you could be looking at, if looking for a 'good' quality where one has a positive opinion of oneself, without the excessiveness or negative conotations of vanity.

> **Self–assured**
> (adjective)  Having or showing confidence in yourself and your abilities.
>
> *Synonyms*: assured, secure, self-asserting, self-assured, self-confident
>
> *Antonyms*: diffident, insecure, self-distrustful, self-doubting

Taken from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-assured).

Comment: "Self confidence" is another term that can be used, and probably one that "flows" better than "self assuredness".

Comment: self conscious is the closest to vain without the negative connotation

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Fitzgerald, [*Word and Phrase: True and False Use in English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4YwiAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%22The+King+James+Bible+has+in+vain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tBMVVYajMY7doATl0YHACA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20King%20James%20Bible%20has%20in%20vain%22&f=false) (1901) offers an interesting perspective on what Fitzgerald sees as a major change in the understood meaning of *vain* between 1611 (when translation of the King James version of the Bible was completed) and 1901 (when Fitzgerald was writing). He writes:

> The King James Bible has "in vain" twenty-five times, the epithet "vain" fifty times, in various connections, the adverb vainly once, vanity and vanities about seventy times. But never once in all those employments of the words is vanity or its derivatives used in the sense which is predominant to-day,—that of love of show, desire of applause or of admiration. Down perhaps to the "Augustan Ag" of English literature, the vice or foible which we denominate vanity was called vainglory, with its proper adjective vainglorious; and vain stood for fruitless, useless, empty, false; in short, vanity and vain were of about the same import s their Latin originals, vanitas, vanus. But the words have been almost emptied of these ancient and true meanings, and in ordinary speech and in current literature there remains but a trace of one of them, adherent to the adjective vain in such phrases as "the effort was vain," "our hopes were vain;" and in these the almost universal usage is "in vain;" ... Vainglory and its derivatives are gone out of common use; it would be almost or quite an affectation to employ them. With the fundamental change in the signification of vain and vanity, it is doubtful whether the modern reader can get at the true meaning of those passages of the Bible in which the words are employed in the  obsolete senses; e.g., the proverb (xxxi. 30) "Favor is deceitful, and beauty is vain" does not mean (even though we read with the Septuagint "woman's beauty") that vainglory, or vanity, in the now generally accepted meaning of the word, goes with a fair face and comely form: only that personal comeliness by itself is of little worth.

But having followed Fitzgerald through his explorations of the possible difference in old and new meanings of *vain*, I think it's fair to say that neither older meanings of *vain* ("fruitless, useless, empty, false") nor the newer ones ("love of show, desire of applause or admiration") can reasonably be described as having positive or even neutral denotations and connotations.

Comment: Dropping by after so many days just to give an example of how "vaidoso/a" can be positive in Portuguese. This is what we'd say about an old lady/man who still cares about the way he looks by taking care of his skin, hair and so on.